# Como utilizar ' dentro de uma array?

Tags: php, wordpress

Estou enfrentando um problema com uma adaptação no `functions.php` do meu tema `Wordpress`.

O que acontece, quero colocar:

```
':'(' => 'choro.png',
```

Só que não é possível pelo segundo `'`

Tentei utilizar:

```
':\'(' => 'choro.png',
```

Só que não funciona.

Estou fazendo uma adaptação nos meus smilyes, o que deveria acontecer é que quando uma pessoa colocar `:'(` aparecesse uma carinha de choro, só que pelo fato do código ser :**'**( não acontece a conversão.

Eu já fiz várias adaptações como: `:)` `;)` `:(` `:|` todas funcionaram bem, só que `:'(` não funciona.

Comment: Porque não usas `":'(" => 'choro.png',` ? Ou seja, aspas a delimitar deixando assim o conteúdo livre para conter plicas.

Comment: tentei utilizar, porém não funciona.

Comment: Defina o que quer dizer com "não funciona". Dá erro, o que acontece?

Comment: Simplesmente não acontece a conversão. Aparece em formato de texto, ou seja, `:'(`

Comment: Precisa ver se o WP não tá fazendo escape de algum valor antes de chegar nesta função. Teste com outros símbolos (letras acentuadas, etc) para ver se acontece o mesmo problema. Por exemplo `'(á)' => 'teste.png'`.

Comment: Funcionou normal com seu `(á)`

Comment: Só que se fizer com `:'(` ele não faz a conversão. Ah! eu percebi que ele muda o acento quando comento `:'(` para `:’(`

Comment: Alguma ideia de solução?

Comment: Teste com `':’(' => 'choro.png'`  entao :)

Comment: Nãooo...... :( :( :( :( Não funcionou.....

Comment: Se eu comentar `:\’(` funciona. Mas tem que funcionar é com `:'(`

Comment: Eu utilizei assim: `":’(" => 'choro.png',` e funcionou perfeitamente quando eu comento `:’(`!! Êbaa.. Só que se eu comentar `:'(` não converte.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Segundo os comentários, o seu código só encontra os smileys quando estes usam `’` ao invés de `'`. Eu usei o WordPress por um tempo, e percebi que ele substituía alguns caracteres por outros na hora de enviar os posts, pela seguinte razão: para usuários comuns, a substituição de `'` por sua variação curvada não implica em nenhuma diferença de funcionalidade, mas deixa os posts mais fáceis de se ler pelo fato de tais símbolos geralmente serem utilizados para marcar citações ou ironia. O Microsoft Word faz a mesma coisa. Experimente digitar algumas citações usando o `"` no Word que você verá que ele as "corrige" para aspas curvadas para um certo lado dependendo do contexto a não ser que você desative o filtro nas configurações.

No WordPress, esse filtro se chama `wptexturize` e altera muitos caracteres, substituindo-os pelas suas variantes curvadas, tais como o `'` (a fonte do seu problema) e as aspas. O problema é que esse filtro não é aplicado na hora de escrever o post, e sim quando ele é salvo no servidor, portanto é realmente difícil saber de onde vem a edição.

Para desativá-lo, abra o arquivo `functions.php` do WordPress e, antes do último `?>`, adicione o seguinte para desativar a substituição em todos os posts que serão criados/editados no futuro:

```
remove_filter ('category_description', 'wptexturize');
remove_filter ('list_cats', 'wptexturize');
remove_filter ('comment_author', 'wptexturize');
remove_filter ('comment_text', 'wptexturize');
remove_filter ('the_title', 'wptexturize');
remove_filter ('the_content', 'wptexturize');
remove_filter ('the_excerpt', 'wptexturize');
```

Devo avisar, porém, que isso não vai afetar posts que já foram criados, então, você terá que re-editar todos os seus posts e, se necessário, substituir todos os `’` dos smileys para `'` novamente. Isso vai facilitar na hora de criar mais códigos de substituição de texto para smileys que usam caracteres que o `wptexturize` modifica.

Comment: Exelente! @Bruno, é isso mesmo que queria. Nota 10! E como faço para desativar só essa parte do `'` que converte para `’`? Caso você não consiga dizer eu vou utilizar seu código, mas só a parte `comment_author` e `comment_text`.

Comment: E esse exemplo? http://pastebin.com/HWYGHDc7 Existe algum jeito de modificá-lo ?

Comment: Eu acabei de testar seu exemplo no `functon.php` do **meu tema**, e ficou show de bola! Muito obrigado...

Answer (score 1):

tente adicionar mais duas barras, pois é provável que a string a ser analisada esteja com addslashes ou magic quotes...

```
<?php
    ':\\\'(' => "choro.png",
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Utilize dessa forma:

```
<?php
    ":'(" => "choro.png",
?>
```

Comment: Em teoria, isto deveria funcionar, mas parece que o [RegEx que o WP aplica](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.9/src/wp-includes/functions.php#L2707) não consegue ver o `'`, nem o `’` e nem escapando a aspa simples `':\'('`

Answer (score 0):

Utilize aspas duplas como delimitador, e fique a vontade para usar aspas simples dentro do valor da mesma:

```
<?php
    ":'(" => "choro.png",
?>
```